# WPF Binding to multiple types based on one type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, polymorphism

I have 2 types of Messages: `ServerMessage` and `UserMessage`. I have a raw string from which I have to create this message.

Here is an example of what would be a server message :

```
:choopa.nj.us.dal.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
```

And here is an example of a user message :

```
:Abc!Abc@2001:123.4234.123.423 PRIVMSG #channelname :hello
```

So first I create a RawMessage with the basics, like the parts of the message and the time etc.

But I have bound this `RawMessage` to my `WPF UI`, and in different parts of the UI it will need different information from the `RawMessage`.

One part, the server window which displays all the `ServerMessages` does not care about the User the message is from as everything is from the server.

However the individual channel windows will need to know the User. So I am being forced into binding the server one with `ServerMessage` types and the channel windows with `UserMessage` types.

Now the problem is when I create the `RawMessage`, do I at that moment check it to see what kind it is, then discard it to make one of the other 2 types then bind that?

Or is there a more elegant polymorphic solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).
When you want represent your message in any way, just apply appropriate data template to control being used.

Comment: I am already using DataTemplates and ContentTemplateSelectors, the confusion is more to do with how I deal with the casting/conversion to a specialised class from a more generic one. I am just looking to see if there is some pattern for this kind of thing where you already have an object and need it to be more specialised.

Comment: Please show code (or pseudo-code) for specific use case, which involves difficulties for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but in my case, I create a base type for messages, and then have various messages classes that inherit this.

I bind a `ListBox` to a collection of `List<Message>` on my view model, and then I have a `DataTemplateSelector` that picks the appropriate template based on the type. That means in each template, I can refernce properties that I know exist on the specific message class...

Comment: In your scenario do you have to create a basic message before you know that its actually a message of type xyz? Thats my scenario. So the question is what is the best way to handle this because its not a typical inheritance scenario, there is now the overheard of destroying the original message and creating a specialised one (because I didnt know originally what type it would end up being). I am looking for a way in which I dont have to destroy the original and can just "add" extra fields/methods to it to avoid the overhead.